# Hide a div at the bottom when it's "empty" (has empty children)

Tags: html, css

I have an alerts table where `tr` elements are dynamicly added/removed using JS. 
The problem is that it has a `border-top` which divides it from the above content which I want to hide when the table is empty. I've tried the `:empty` with `display:none` but the bottom div has children so that doesn't work.

## HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <table id="alerts">
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#top {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
    max-height: 30%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

table#alerts {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Any non-JavaScript ideas?

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hB4SM/)

Comment: Why non-JavaScript when you are already using it to remove the elements?

Comment: I prefer not to use JS for styling if it can be avoided.

Comment: Even when you are just talking about hiding an element? Did [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hB4SM/2/) just to show a jquery solution. Click the rows to make them disappear.

Comment: @smerny The code is a little more complex than this snippet, if it can be done with CSS it's cleaner. If not I'll build in the extra check.

Answer (score 1):

I would either use the method that removes/adds messages to also set a class to `#bottom` to indicate that no border should be displayed.

For example:

```
#bottom.no-border {
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Another option would be to draw the border on the first table row. That way it is only displayed if there actually is a table row.

```
#alerts tr:first-child {
    border-top: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks: `table{width: 100%;}tbody{border-top: 5px solid blue;}tbody:empty{border: none;}` gets me almost there, but the scrollbar still overlaps `#bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, why are you opposed to using JavaScript for this? This is exactly why JavaScript is so useful, it allows you to do things like this extremely simply.  You could just run a test when the page is loading to see if the table is empty and if so, set `border-top: none;`